# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Guzzle\Service\Command\Factory\AliasFactory' not found in

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, server, onstart

I am trying to run this php script

```
sudo php S3Client.php
```

however I receive this erreur that I can't find a solution for it

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient' not found in /etc/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/S3/S3Client.php on line 121
```

and this the Script of S3client.php

```
namespace Aws\S3;
use Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient;
use Aws\Common\Client\ClientBuilder;
use Aws\Common\Client\ExpiredCredentialsChecker;
use Aws\Common\Client\UploadBodyListener;
use Aws\Common\Enum\ClientOptions as Options;
use Aws\Common\Exception\RuntimeException;
use Aws\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Aws\Common\Signature\SignatureV4;
use Aws\Common\Model\MultipartUpload\AbstractTransfer;
use Aws\S3\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Aws\S3\Exception\Parser\S3ExceptionParser;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Aws\S3\Model\ClearBucket;
use Aws\S3\Model\MultipartUpload\AbstractTransfer as AbstractMulti;
use Aws\S3\Model\MultipartUpload\UploadBuilder;
use Aws\S3\Sync\DownloadSyncBuilder;
use Aws\S3\Sync\UploadSyncBuilder;
use Guzzle\Common\Collection;
use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;
use Guzzle\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Guzzle\Iterator\FilterIterator;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\BackoffPlugin;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\CurlBackoffStrategy;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\ExponentialBackoffStrategy;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\HttpBackoffStrategy;
use Guzzle\Plugin\Backoff\TruncatedBackoffStrategy;
use Guzzle\Service\Command\CommandInterface;
use Guzzle\Service\Command\Factory\AliasFactory;
use Guzzle\Service\Command\Factory\CompositeFactory;
use Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model;
use Guzzle\Service\Resource\ResourceIteratorInterface;
```

this is the first time that I work with PHP code and s3 so for that I am blocked
appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

What the error means that Class "Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient" cannot be found in your file.

This might be because you have not included the correct file or the file you are referring to doesn't exist.

Did you add the autoloader above the class?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

See the documentation for aws -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_basic-usage.html